# Java readLine and PHP write interaction

Tags: java, php, tcp, client-server

I have a strange trouble with TCP server (Java) and client (PHP). Java server hangs at a readLine..

Please see code above.

Java server:

```
       while (true) {

            Socket clientSocket = null;

            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String inputLine;

            if ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
                out.println(handleCommand(inputLine));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ooops...");
            }
        }
```

PHP client:

```
$fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 6789, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$result = '';

if (!$fp) {
    ErrorLog(ALERT, "-", "Unable to connect to java server! $errstr ($errno)");
    $result = 'ERROR|Unable to connect to RmServer';
} else {
    fwrite($fp, $command.PHP_EOL);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I also tried on a client side:

fwrite($fp, $command."\n");
fwrite($fp, $command."\r\n");

But result is the same.

But when I use Java client it works fine! May be it is some encoding related problem? I think some magic happens when I type ENTER after command in console.

Java client(works) code:

```
        if ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
            System.out.print("input: ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Opppppps..");
        }
```

**ADD:**
If I send empty string by Java client after sending by PHP client I see the following output:
Server: test\ntest\n

Comment: maybe line feed isn't required: try with fwrite($fp, $command);

Comment: Unfortunately it does not it